# Open installed app instead of website from PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My PWA has a page with a list of links to various social media sites of our institution. When users click on a link, I would like to send them directly to the installed app instead of the default browser, and use the browser only as a fallback if the given app is not installed.

The previous version of my PWA was a native Android app written in Java, where I was able to check whether the given app is installed by its package name, and either open the app or the default browser. Basically, I would like to have a similar behavior.

With `mailto:`, `tel:` and `geo:` URLs I can trigger the app selector dialog, but with `https://` it does not work. So far I can only make the link open in the default browser instead of inside my PWA using the `target="_blank"` attribute, but it's still not ideal.

I have discovered that apps don't work the same in this situation. For example, a Facebook link launches the browser, but automatically redirects to the native app in a second. On the other hand, an Instagram link just launches the browser and loads the page in it. I guess it's because the two apps don't have the same URL handling logic.

Is there any solution to force the OS to open the app if it's installed, or trigger the app selector dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of my answer, but I had the same issue in my PWA when I wanted to open links from the PWA to instagram, that opened insta in the user browser instead of the insta app that was installed on the device.

I solved it using

```
window.open(`https://www.instagram.com/${path}`);
```

Instead of a regular  link.

It might not be 100% bulletproof, because sometime it still open in the browser, I think it's because the insta app is not already opened on the device.
Give it a try!

-- EDIT

While looking at my code base I've noticed that I do something different to open the instagram app on Android vs iOS from the PWA.

On Android:

```
href='intent://instagram.com/_u/experiences_luxe/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.instagram.android;end'
```

One iOS:

```
href='https://www.instagram.com/experiences_luxe/'
```

From what I recall, either version worked only on one OS and not the other, so I have a condition to handle each one.

I'm assuming it's going to be a similar format for Facebook as it's Meta, but I didn't tried.

Comment: It's strange, but the regular `<a href>` solution seems to work the same as you've described.